# Intellisense (autocompletion) for model in Laravel for Visual Studio Code or another IDE

Tags: laravel, autocomplete, ide, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am looking for sth similiar to Intellisense in .NET in Laravel. So far I've been using .NET and autocompletion for models is awesome and makes my work way more easy.

Now I need to create Laravel application, I've been following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@ardanirohman/laravel-%EF%B8%8F-visual-studio-code-debug-environment-65440274d3b0) to prepare my environment but the only autocompletion I get is for default PHP functions and some predefined methods (ex. `SaveSessionListener` from `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener` - I am not even using Symfony anywhere).

What I'd like to achieve is get autocompletion from models, for example there is a class called Model in Laravel, I have class Page which extends Model.

```
use App/Page

$home = new Page();
$home->content = "lorem ipsum";
$home->save();
```

I don't have any completion when I write `$home->`, no `content`, no `save()`, only some random functions. I can understand why there might be no `content` autocompletion - its not written directly into code, but its written on database and object-database engine is parsing that one, I didn't figure out how yet, but I don't understand why even `save()` doesn't get autocompletion.

I tried to google the issue, but without any good result.

Comment: take a look at `laravel-ide-helper` package https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Comment: Seems a little bit complicated way, but I've look through docs and its promising. I'll test it later.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I figured it out how to get it work with Visual Studio Code.

**First and most important** is the link morph provided me in comment:
[laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper)

I just followed docs and generated basic helper + model helper. I guess later I'll automate those generation commands, its also explained how to do it in docs.

**Second thing** is that it works only with:
[PHP Intelephense plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client)
Note that you need to reset VSC before it actually works.

**Third thing I did** - VSC have build-in php autocompletion, it was pretty annoying cause it started to show me model fields in suggestions, but it was between dozens of other suggestions. To disable build-in autocompletion I added line to user settings:

```
"php.suggest.basic": false,
```

**Last thing I did** - I have moved snippets to bottom of suggestions box to clear autocompletion results a little bit more:

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "bottom"
```

**And that works really decent as Laravel programming environment.**

Comment: Thanks a lot... it worked for me =) i have autocompletion now (laravel 5.8)

Answer (score 5):

I use *PHP Doc* for fields definition like following example:

```php
namespace App\Models;

use App\Enums\MediaType;
use App\Models\Commons\BaseModel;
use DateTime;

/**
 * Famous Media.
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property int $famous_id
 * @property MediaType $type
 * @property string $url
 * @property int $position
 * @property DateTime $created_at
 * @property DateTime $updated_at
 */
class FamousMedia extends BaseModel
{
  const TABLE = 'famous_medias';

  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable = [
    'type',
    'url',
    'position',
    'famous_id',
  ];

  /**
   * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $hidden = [
    'famous_id',
    'deleted_at',
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
  ];

  public function famous()
  {
    return $this->hasOne(Famous::class, 'famous_id');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

You can now use [Laravel Extra Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=amiralizadeh9480.laravel-extra-intellisense) is now supporting Model Attributes.

Still in **Beta** but it works fine.